# Requests: what is the difference between cert and verify?

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, python-requests, pyinstaller

What is the difference between cert and verify?

From Documentation:

verify – (optional) if True, the SSL cert will be verified. A CA_BUNDLE path can also be provided.
cert – (optional) if String, path to ssl client cert file (.pem). If Tuple, (‘cert’, ‘key’) pair.

Does this mean I can do the following:

```
CA_BUNDLE='path/to/.pem'
requests.get(url=google.com, verify= CA_BUNDLE)
```

or

```
Cert='path/to/.pem'
requests.get(url=google.com, cert=Cert)
```

They both look like they do the same thing. except verify can disable ssl verification.

I am trying to compile my code to an exe using PYinstaller. I am using certifi module that I see already has a cacert.pem file but I guess I still have to bundle it with my code.

In my code do I modify ...verify or cert?...with a path to cacert.pem or just 'cacert.pem'?

Answer (score 5):

I think it is clearly stated in the documentation: [SSL Cert Verification](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)

The option `cert` is to send you own certificate, e.g. authenticate yourself against the server using a client certificate. It needs a certificate file and if the key is not in the same file as the certificate also the key file.

The option `verify` is used to enable (default) or disable verification of the servers certificate. It can take True or False or a name of a file which contains the trusted CAs. If not given I think (not documented?) it will take the default CA path/file from OpenSSL, which works usually on UNIX (except maybe OS X) and not on windows.

Comment: Im going to bundle my pem file. Then I can do which of the following: verify=bundledfile.pem or verify=path/to/bundledfile.pem ?

Comment: Probably the same way you open a file: if you need to specify an absolute path use this, but if relative is enough you don't need to specify an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

if the `*.pem` file has this section

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
....
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

then use `cert`

---

and if not, then use `verify`